# Custom NSUserNotifictation object

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsusernotification

I am trying to modify the NSUserNotifictation to pass custom variables:

```
@interface MyUserNotification: NSUserNotification
@property (nonatomic) int theid;
@property (nonatomic) NSString* url;
@end

@implementation MyUserNotification
@end
```

Then when initiating in my `AppDelegate` object:

```
MyUserNotification *notification = [[MyUserNotification alloc] init];
notification.theid = theid;
```

setting `theid` throws the error:

```
-[_NSConcreteUserNotification setTheid:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100204840
```

Why is `NSConcreteUserNotification` object getting involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so this class isn't meant to be overridden it seems, but good news: there a [userInfo](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsusernotification/1415675-userinfo?language=objc) dict?

So you can store whatever objects as KV pairs in a userInfo dict...

```
int theid;
NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
NSDictionary * userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[userInfo setValue:@(theid) forKey:@"theid"];
notification.userInfo = userInfo;
```

Comment: Cheers I will use: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsusernotification/1415675-userinfo just got excited about customising objects

Comment: @Maximilian the reason that it works this way will never be apparent to us mortals, but it is implemented with class clusters, and usually we never need to know the "why".